# Repeated measures tests without "before and after" measurements

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

When reading about repeated measures ANOVA, until now 99% of examples are always with "before" and "after".

But if I understood correctly the point of repeated measures ANOVA is not necessarily to estimate differences *in time* but rather when one measure may be dependent on another, correct?

Can you mention examples of repeated measures ANOVA (or any other test for that matter, like paired t test) which do NOT involve measuring something before and after? Ideally, an example where time is not a factor to consider...

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of these.

Suppose you have data on spouses and want to predict whether the husband or wife does more of the child care.

Suppose you have data on students in classes and want to look at test scores.

Or on left eyes and right eyes and want to predict acuity of vision.

And lots more.